# Tkinter: maximize matplotlib GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

So it appears that matplotlib gui plots (a la `plt.show()`) don't adapt to monitor resolution and appear tiny on high resolution screens. Is there a matplotlib/tkinter fix or do I have fiddle around somewhere in Windows settings?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `plt.show()` call these functions:

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.frame.Maximize(True)
```

Maybe it solve your issue.